# Reduce by multiple columns in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Having dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "group0": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
        "group1": ["1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"],
        "relevant": [True, False, False, True, True, True],
        "value": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    }
)
```

I wish to produce a target

```py
target = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "group0": [1, 2, 2, 3],
        "group1": ["1","1", "2", "2",],
        "value": [0, 2, 3, 5],
    }
)
```

where `"value"` has been chosen by

1. Maximum of all positive `"relevant"` indices in `"value"` column
2. Otherwise maximum of `"value"` if no positive `"relevant"` indices exist

This would be produced by

```py
def fun(x):
    tmp = x["value"][x["relevant"]]
    if len(tmp):
        return tmp.max()
    return x["value"].max()
```

were `x` a groupby dataframe.

Is it possible to achive the desired groupby reduction efficiently?

EDIT:

with payload

```py
from time import perf_counter()
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "group0": np.random.randint(0, 30,size=10_000_000),
        "group1": np.random.randint(0, 30,size=10_000_000),
        "relevant": np.random.randint(0, 1, size=10_000_000).astype(bool),
        "value": np.random.random_sample(size=10_000_000) * 1000,
    }
)

start = perf_counter()
out = (df
   .sort_values(by=['relevant', 'value'])
   .groupby(['group0', 'group1'], as_index=False)
   ['value'].last()
 )
end = perf_counter()
print("Sort values", end - start)

def fun(x):
    tmp = x["value"][x["relevant"]]
    if len(tmp):
        return tmp.max()
    return x["value"].max()

start = perf_counter()
out = df.groupby(["group0", "group1"]).apply(fun)
end = perf_counter()
print("Apply", end - start)
#Sort values 14.823943354000221
#Apply 1.5050544870009617
```

`.apply`-solution got time of 1.5s. The solution with `sort_values` performed with 14.82s. However, reducing sizes of the test groups with

```
...
        "group0": np.random.randint(0, 500_000,size=10_000_000),
        "group1": np.random.randint(0, 100_000,size=10_000_000),
...
```

led to vastly superior performance by the `sort_values` solution.
(15.29s versus 1423.84s). `sort_values` solution by [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76579362/8219760) is preferred, unless user specifically knows that data contains small group counts.

Comment: Do you have some negative values as `value`?

Comment: In my use case, probably not. I'd think, however, a generic solution would be desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the values to put `True`, then highest number last and use a [`groupby.last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.last.html):

```
out = (df
   .sort_values(by=['relevant', 'value'])
   .groupby(['group0', 'group1'], as_index=False)
   ['value'].last()
 )
```

Output:

```
   group0 group1  value
0       1      1      0
1       2      1      2
2       2      2      3
3       3      2      5
```

Intermediate before aggregation:

* selected rows

```
   group0 group1  relevant  value
1       1      1     False      1
2       2      1     False      2  *
0       1      1      True      0  *
3       2      2      True      3  *
4       3      2      True      4
5       3      2      True      5  *
```

Comment: This was the solution with the highest performance.

Comment: It seems that it did not scale that well after a more extensive testing. A more applied solution in any case!

Comment: Sorting is O(n*logn), so it might be limiting if you have very large groups

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to achieve the desired `groupby` reduction efficiently. Here is the modified code:

```
def fun(x):
    tmp = x["value"][x["relevant"]]
    if len(tmp):
        return tmp.max()
    return x["value"].max()
```

You can achieve this to get the desired output without modifying your function and you can apply groupby function in your function.

```
target  = df.groupby(["group0", "group1"]).apply(fun).reset_index(name='value')
print(target)
```

here is the desired output:

```
     group0   group1  value
0       1      1      0
1       2      1      2
2       2      2      3
3       3      2      5
```

Comment: This is probably the go to solution although all other solutions work as well! This is also something I originally attempted, but for some reason I got column name errors with input of shape `(1,)`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not as elegant as other solutions, but also works:

```
group_keys = ["group0","group1"]
rev = df[df.relevant].groupby(group_keys).max()
nrev = df[~df.relevant].groupby(group_keys).max()
merged = rev.merge(nrev, on=group_keys, how='outer')
merged['value'] =  merged.value_x.where(merged.relevant_x, merged.value_y )
merged
```